# Updated to Puppet 3.5.0 and puppet apply does not work

Tags: puppet

So I have updated my Puppet version to 3.5.0 and puppet apply command which worked before is not working anymore. I have a certname defined in ~/.puppet/puppet.conf:

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
templatedir=$confdir/templates
manifestdir=$confdir/manifests
parser=future
certname=app.staging.hello.world

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN 
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
```

I am running command:

```
cd ~/.puppet and sudo puppet apply manifests/
```

And getting:

```
Error: Could not find default node or by name with 'ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal, ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute, ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1, ip-x-x-x-x' on node ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal
Error: Could not find default node or by name with 'ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal, ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute, ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1, ip-x-x-x-x' on node ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

In ~/.puppet/manifests I have app.pp with node matching the certname:

```
node /^app\d*\.staging\d*\.(.*)$/
```

Why isn't Puppet picking it up?

Comment: because ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal does not match /^app\d*\.staging\d*\.(.*)$/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Puppet 3.5.0 got recalled due to issues uncovered after release.

Definitely downgrade or wait until 3.5.1 is out.

[Recall notice](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-announce/97S-Pcx875Y)

Answer (score 0):

If this error goes away by downgrading to 3.4.3, then this is likely a bug. There has been a change to the parser that might cause such a regression. I cannot really tell.

Would you open a ticket at [Puppet's Jira](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/)?